# Express promisify with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'll start off and say I don't know if this is the issue, but it may very well be (hoping).

I'm using axios to post data to an API.

The data posts successfully, but never gets to the .then function. ie:

```
  createPage(page) {
    instance.post('/admin/createPage',page).then((response) => {
      console.log(response) <------- Never gets to.
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

I do not get the console.log(response).

I ended up adding 'es6-promisify', but how would I set that up?

For reference, here are the important files:

server.js:

```
import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import promisify from 'es6-promisify'
import cors from 'cors'
import low from 'lowdb'
import fileAsync from 'lowdb/lib/storages/file-async'

import { initDb } from './db/index.js'
import routes from './routes/index.js'

const app = express();

const db = low('./core/db/.index.json', { storage: fileAsync })

app.use(cors())

app.set('db', db);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req,res, next) => {
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);

if(!db.has('pages').value()) {
    initDb(db);
}



const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

import Header from '../components/Header'

import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import AddEditPage from './AddEditPage'

const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:1337'})



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "pages": []
    }
    this.createPage = this.createPage.bind(this)
    this.getPages = this.getPages.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPages()
  }

  getPages() {
    instance.get('/admin/listPages')
      .then(
        (response) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              "pages": response.data
            }
          )
        })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }

  createPage(page) {
    instance.post('/admin/createPage',page).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="Router">
          <div className="Navbar">
            <Header />
          </div>
          <div className="Wrapper">
            <Route exact path="/" render={ () => (
              <Dashboard pages={this.state.pages} />
            )} />
            <Route path="/admin/new-page" render={ () => (
              <AddEditPage createPage={this.createPage} />
            )} />
            <Route path="/admin/edit-page/:id" render={ () => (
              <AddEditPage />
            )} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include your `./routes/index.js` so we don't know your actual routes are and what request handlers do they use, so we can only speculate about it, but what you described is a symptom that happens when you don't return a response from your request handler.

For example, if you have something like:

```
router.post('/createPage', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

then your request will hang forever (util it times out).

If you return a response:

```
router.post('/createPage', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({ ok: true });
});
```

then the request should end and return success.

But of course you didn't include enough code to know that for sure.